# Apache reverse proxy logic based on arbitrary header

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, apache-2.2

I have apache running on a natting fw, that authenticates, reverse proxies, and provides an ssl wrapper for 2 webapps on the back end.  This works with virtual hosting and proxies back based on the top level directory of the request, e.g. `https://example.com/app1/ <-> http://app1/app1/`. (see fig1)

I would like to find a way to proxy back a request to a webservice based on an arbitrary header set in the request, e.g. if header web_service:coolwebservice is set, it proxies back to webservice:8000.  Is this even possible?

```
fig1      [Apache:example.com:443 / FW / NAT]
                          |
       ┌------------------┬------------------┐
       |                  |                  |
       V                  V                  V
[app1:80 /app1/]  [app2:8080 /app2/] [web_service:8000]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible with mod_rewrite, something like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:web-service} coolwebservice
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://web_service:8000/$1 [P,L]
```

With `%{HTTP:...}` you can inspect aritrary headers and make your decisions based on that.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I ended up working around this because I couldn't figure it out, but I'll revisit it.